# Java-Linux-SWT Button Background Corners

Tags: java, linux, swt

I have a button, and changed its backgroundcolor, but it changes the color in the corners too. (the rounded button changes its color AND the not-button-background of the button).

[image: These corners are orange too]

next, i cant find, how to change the "hover" color of the button... :P

how can i change both colors?

thankyou

(Im using easy-eclipse and swt)